# Updating objects containing arrays in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, typegoose

I have an object coming in from the frontend, structure of which is as follows:

```json
{
    name: 'John Doe',
    gender: 'male',
    age: 28,
    preferredTags: ["JavaScipt", "Rails", "AWS"]
}
```

and I have a typegoose schema that is defined as:

```js
    class DocSchema {
      @prop({ type: String })
      public identifier?: String;

      @prop({ type: form1SubDoc })
      public form1SubDoc?: form1SubDoc;
    }


    class form1SubDoc {
      _id?: mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

      @prop({ type: String, required: true })
      public name!: String;
     
      @prop({ type: String })
      public gender?: String;

      @prop({ type: Number })
      public age?: Number;

      @prop({ type: [String] })
      public preferredTags?: String[];
    }

    const MainDoc = getModelForClass(DocSchema);
    export default MainDoc;
```

Whenever I try to implement the following logic:

```js
// MainDoc document was already created. I am trying to update it. form1SubDoc wasn't initiated initially

const form1Pointer = await MainDoc.findOne({some_logic_here});
if(form1Pointer) {
   form1Pointer.form1SubDoc = the_json_object_mentioned_above_coming_from_the_frontend;
   await form1Pointer.save()
}
```

I get this error:

```json
   {
      Cast to string failed for value "[ 'JavaScript', 'Rails', 'AWS' ]" (type Array) at 
      path "preferredTags"
      {
        {
           stringValue: `"[ 'JavaScript', 'Rails', 'AWS' ]"`,
           messageFormat: undefined,
           kind: 'string',
           value: [Array],
           path: 'preferredTags',
           reason: null,
           valueType: 'Array'
         }
         _message: 'DocSchema validation failed'
       }
   }
```

What am I doing wrong? Whenever I don't update the array, the data is added to the database successfully.

Comment: what version of mongoose and typegoose are you running?

Comment: @hasezoey,  
`"mongoose": "^6.3.2", "@typegoose/typegoose": "^9.8.1"`

Comment: i cannot reproduce your error, do you maybe have "DocSchema" and "form1SubDoc" in different files? if not maybe try switching the places of the classes because of "Cannot access 'form1SubDoc' before initialization" see [typegoose-testing SO72625987](https://github.com/typegoose/typegoose-testing/tree/SO72625987).

Comment: Why use `type` in the first place ? Typegoose does this for you

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to warp `type: [String]`, do `type: String` instead (cf. [Typegoose doc](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/api/decorators/prop#type))

```
class Dummy {
  @prop({ type: String })
  public hello: string[];
}
```

But even better, you should simply remove it
`type` lets you overwrite the TS/mongo types when needed, and you don't need it here. Both Typescript and mongodb will use `string[]` with full compatibility.

```
class Dummy {
  @prop()
  public hello: string[];
}
```